# Array has more params than PDO prepared statement causes error

Tags: php, pdo

If Have to execute several queries. Some of the parameters overlap, some do not.

I wanted to create one array containing the data for all the params for all the queries.

I figured if the array contains values that the prepared statement does not, it would ignore them but its giving me this error:

> Invalid parameter number: number of
>   bound variables does not match number
>   of tokens

here is what I mean:

```
$data = array( 'a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c, 'd' => $d);

$data['e'] = "e";
$STH = $this->PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 ( fieldA, fieldB, fieldE ) VALUES (:a, :b, :e )");
$STH->execute($data);

$data['f'] = "f";
$STH = $this->PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO table2 ( fieldA, fieldD, fieldF ) VALUES (:a, :d, :f )");
$STH->execute($data);
```

Is there a way to allow this? or do have to create a different array each time?

Comment: side-note: The error message indicates that PDO uses emulated prepared statements. In case you're using PDO_MYSQL that's the default since php 5.1.something. The reason was apparently MySQL not using the query cache for prepared statements until server version 5.1.17. If you're using a server >= 5.1.17 you might want to set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to 0 - depending on how you actually use the statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not supported.

BTW, when it comes to maintaining I always felt using the bindParam method results in much more readable code. Like this...

```
$STH = $this->PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 ( fieldA, fieldB, fieldE ) VALUES (:a, :b, :e )");
$STH->bindParam(':a', 'a');
$STH->bindParam(':b', 'b');
$STH->bindParam(':e', 'e');
$STH->execute();
```